# Вычитание ячеек в таблице SQL

Tags: sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить такую задачу: в MySQL есть таблица в которую поступают каждые 10 минут данные о кол-ве всего собранных коробок.  Как вычислить сколько коробок собрано за 10минут (т.е нужно от кол-ва во второй строке отнять кол-во в первой строке, от кол-ва в третьей строке отнять кол-во во второй строке и т.д.) и записывать результат в отдельный столбец таблицы в MySQL.

Comment: Используйте функцию LAG()

Comment: Сергей, покажите структуру Ваших таблиц и ваши попытки получения нужных вам данных

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь